# Automatic Image ID creator

Tags: vb.net

I am developing automatic image id creator using vs2008. Using Excel file, folder images for image. Below is my code. I want all images to be placed and printed as shown in the attachment.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles btnOk.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim openFileDialog2 As System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog  
        While True
            While True
                Select Case i
                    Case 1         
                        Dim openFileDialog1 As System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog = New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
                        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Supported files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv?"
                        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
                        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select data file?"
                        openFileDialog2 = openFileDialog1
                        openFileDialog2.FileName = txtPath.Text
                        openFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
                        i = 2
                        GoTo label_1

                    Case 2
                            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString(openFileDialog2.FileName,  "?", False) = 0 Then
                                GoTo label_1
                            End If
                            i = 1
                End Select    
            End While

            If Not 0 Then

            End If

            txtPath.Text = openFileDialog2.FileName    
            txtPath.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black    
            i = 0    
        End While

        label_1: _    
        openFileDialog2 = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog2_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog2.FileOk   
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog2.OpenFile()
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName.ToString()

        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then   
            'insert code to read the file data
            strm.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("file closed")
        End If    
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         OpenFileDialog2.Title = "Please Select a File"    
        'OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:\"    
        'OpenFileDialog2.Title = "Open a Text File"    
        'OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()    
        'OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:\Book11.xls"    
        'OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xls)|*.xls"    
        OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Word Files|*.doc|Text|*.txt"   
        ' OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
        'OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "TextFile Files(*.text)|*.Text"    
        OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
        '===========================    

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection    
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet    
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter    
        'Dim cbo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell    
        'MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +  Txt_Path.Text.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source='C:\TamilGrocery\Book1.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)    
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")    
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet    
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)    
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)    
        MyConnection.Close()    
        'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = Image.FromFile("C:\TamilGrocery\WindowsApplication1\1.jpg")

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1    
           ComboBox1.Items.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name)    
        Next

        'Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()  
        ' cmb.HeaderText = "ProID"    
        'cmb.Name = "cmb"    
        'cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 6    
        ' cmb.Items.Add("True")    
        ' cmb.Items.Add("False")    
        ' DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)    
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ' Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
        ' Dim inImg As Image = Image.FromFile("\C:\TamilGrocery\WindowsApplicatio\Imag\1000.jpg")    
        ' img.Image = inImg    
        ' DataGridView1.Columns.Add(img)    
        ' img.HeaderText = "Image"    
        'img.Name = "img"
        '================

        'DtSet.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Number LIKE" & txtNumber.Text & "'"          
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0).DefaultView

         Dim textbox1 As New TextBox     
         textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"          
         textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 20)           
         textbox1.Location = New Point(167, 32)         
         GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)

         AddHandler textbox1.TextChanged, AddressOf Text_Changed

 End Sub

 Private Sub Text_Changed(ByVal eventSender As System.Object,ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs)

    Dim txt As String = eventSender.Text           
    If IsNumeric(txt) Then

    Else             
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter numeric value")          
    End If

 End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

       If e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then 'assumed third column is for image change the value based on what column your image need to bind

           If e.Value IsNot Nothing And Not TypeOf e.Value Is Bitmap Then               
               e.Value = Image.FromFile(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, e.Value.ToString))                
               e.FormattingApplied = True             
           End If         
       End If      
  End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DatabaseDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.    
        'Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseDataSet.Table1)    
        ' Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()    
End Sub


Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

 End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged   

End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
        textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"
        textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 20)
        textbox1.Location = New Point(167, 32)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)

    End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

        Dim label1 As New Label    
        label1.Name = "label1"    
        label1.Text = "Enter Name"   
        label1.AutoSize = True    
        label1.Location = New Point(80, 33)    
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(label1)

    End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: Too much code, not [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: In which event you will create that auto ID ?

Comment: Please a) post only the relevant parts of your code and b) take the time to format your code...this is like reading a double-spaced high school book report. :)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  And please only post relevant code.  We don't need to see your empty loops, subs, commented-out portions, etc.